# How to specify decimal places when formatting NSNumber objects?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm using the following piece of Objective-C code to format a NSNumber, and it works fine most of the time, but it doesn't quite do what I want when the NSNumber object holds an integer (no fractional part).

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80.0f, 90.0f, 225.0f, 40.0f)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setFormat:@"###.##"];
int bytes = 1024 * 1024;
NSNumber *total = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([self.totalFileSize floatValue] / bytes)];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.00 MB of %@ MB", [formatter stringFromNumber:total]];
```

So for instance, if `self.totalFileSize` holds 55.2300, it will display "55.23" as it should on my `UILabel`. But if that same variable holds 55, it will simply display "55" on the label.

What I really want is for this code to always include the 2 decimal places in the output.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your format string should have a "`0`" for each decimal place you want to always exist.

```
[formatter setFormat:@"###.00"];
```

for "55.23" and ".23" and ".20"

```
[formatter setFormat:@"##0.00"];
```

for "55.23" and "0.23" and "0.20"

See [Number Format String Syntax (Mac OS X Versions 10.0 to 10.3)](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/df100103.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000195-SW11)

Or you can use a 10.4 formatter with [- setMinimumFractionDigits:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMinimumFractionDigits:) and [- setMaximumFractionDigits:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMaximumFractionDigits:) with both set to 2.

Comment: setFormat: Is not available for iOS(might work in simulator, but not on device).  You need to use setPositiveFormat: and setNegativeFormat:

Comment: on iOS you need to use  `setMinimumFractionDigits:` and/or - `setMaximumFractionDigits:`

Answer (score 7):

I believe what you are looking for is: "%.2f"

Worst case scenario, you can split the value, check if there is anything after the decimal. If there isn't add the 00 by hand?

Comment: I believe what you meant you believe what he is looking for is: "%.2f" ;)

Comment: Using that won't do what you think it will, as passing a NSNumber object to NSLog will result in it calling [obj description], which returns a string. In any case, I'm trying to avoid hacks like the "append 00 if it's not there". I'm sure NSNumberFormatter has a feature to do what I want here.

Comment: @Garret, I was desperate to find this simple solution. Number formatting is not easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You might be better off with localizedStringWithFormat, like so...

```
[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80.0f, 90.0f, 225.0f, 40.0f)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
int bytes = 1024 * 1024;
label.text = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"0.00 MB of %.2f MB", ([self.totalFileSize floatValue] / bytes)];
```

And of course, *bytes* could be a *const unsigned*, and clearColor tends to be a performance hog, but those are issues for another thread.

Comment: What is the problem with using `clearColor` and what would be better? Thanks you very much!

Comment: thanks for the `localizedStringWithFormat` hint. I was desperately looking for a easy way to ensure localized decimal separator.